# jquery generate simplified version of cloned tables

Tags: jquery

I am dynamically creating new cloned tables. Each table will be different with different colors in each td's and different html inserted by the user. My cloned tables contain 5 td's each time.

What I would like to achieve, is that once all the tables have been created, so lets say 5 new tables are created, that with a button, a simplified version of each table is created. Only taking the first and the last td's.

Here the Original tables created

[image: The original tables]

Here the simplified Table

[image]

Here is a fiddle of how I am working this round here.
The `<button id="simple_button">generate simple table</button>` would be the button to generate the simple tables.
The simplified table would need to be editable in css so its css doesn't correspond to sizing of the original.

[JSFIDDLE EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/adrienboufflet/66nruhh2/2/)

Comment: the table cells have similar id's. so search and hide or remove (.remove()).  http://jsfiddle.net/p4faqgoy/ --- http://jsfiddle.net/a03y6bem/

Comment: yes this could be a work around my problem. The thing is that this doesn't really allow me to modify how the simplified tables will look like. for example placing TD05_2 under TD01_2. and to the right of this placing TD01_3 with TD05_3 bellow it.

Comment: you should put that in your question with a screenshot like your original question

Comment: I have just edited my question. Hope it makes thing a little clearer.

Comment: when you clone a table you are cloning the table id too and you must have unique id's. You may need a different approach to generate unique tables but for now i prepared another  demo for what you require wrapping all the tables within a div -- http://jsfiddle.net/wdozqo46/

Comment: This is great. Thank you. I understand the ids problem. this fiddle was a simplified version of my original code to make things a little easier to understand. I will need to figure out a way to work around your code so that a button will change the layout view of the tables and not have to limit it to a assigned count. In your code 5. the point is to have the user choose when he needs to change the table view.